# how to use QueryRunner Class to delete records

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How can I use QueryRunner Class to delete records from mysql database? ids are passed as an array of String. Also can you advise if using apache common db utils for DML operations is any good and what are the alternatives or best practices?

Below is an extract from my StudentDAO.java class.

```
            public boolean deleteStudent(String [] ids) {

            Connection connection = null;
            String query;
            boolean result = false;

            try {
                Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
                Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/cmsDB");
                connection = ds.getConnection();

                QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner(ds);
                query = "delete tbl_student where student_id";// what should i put here???
                int nor = run.update(query, ids); //nor = no of records

                if (nor > 0) {
                    result = true;
                } else {
                    result = false;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                DbUtils.closeQuietly(connection);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String join(String[] s, String delimiter) {
    int imax = s.length;
    String strJoin="";
    if (imax > 1) {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < imax-1; i++) {
            strJoin += s[i] + delimiter;

        }
        strJoin += s[i];            
    }
    else
        strJoin += s[0];
    return strJoin;
}

public boolean deleteStudent(String [] ids) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    query = "delete tbl_student where student_id in ("+ join(ids,",") +")";
    ...
    ...
    ...
]
```